# What is this bizarre syntax in a c++ Struct?

Tags: c++

```
struct mybitfields
{
    unsigned short a : 4;
    unsigned short b : 5;
    unsigned short c : 7;
} test;
```

Why is the `:` used instead of `=`. I'm really confused.

Comment: It's called a bit-field: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

Comment: It's a bit-field. In the case of `a : 4`, it means 4 bits are used for `a`, meaning `a` can only store small values, specifically `0-15`. The advantage is its very small. But how exactly the bits are stored is up to the compiler.

Comment: @VoidStar how's this different than a union?

Comment: @Celeritas: In a union, `a`, `b`, and `c` would be overlapped, providing views to the same memory; for example, setting  `a` would also set `c`. In a bit field, `a`, `b`, and `c` are usable as separate values. They are just packed really close together.

Comment: @VoidStar right I see they are quite different, though bit-fields seem really useless as memory isn't bit addressable: at best it's byte addressable. Assuming 8 bit bytes `a` and `b` still take 2 bytes...

Comment: @Celeritas: Addressing doesn't matter, you can't even take the address of a bit field anyway. If you created say, eight 1-bit bit fields, the compiler might decide to pack them all into a single byte in memory, using bitwise operators (under the covers) to get/set the individual bits. It will pack them however it thinks is smallest and best-aligned.

Answer (score 2):

This is bit fields and it is used to specify that struct members occupies exactly given number of bits.

In your example it is 4 bits for `test.a`, 5 for `test.b` and 7 bits for `test.c`.

This is useful for typecasting for example. You can have `short` variable that can be cast to `test` and get exactly needed bits.

Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe.aspx) for more information.

Comment: `test` is the variable name, not the type